# Can I have a bunch of lapel pins on my personal backpack that will be in the seat in front of me or should I take them off?

Tags: hand-luggage, american-airlines

[image: backpack with dozens of small metal pins]

My backpack has many pins on it to show where all I have traveled. Would American Airlines allow me to carry that with those on or take them all off?

Comment: Are they allowed through security?

Comment: AA shouldn’t mind or care. The only issue could have been security, but TSA allows them.